# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: data/kitti_label_map.pbtxt; No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm trying to convert the kitti dataset into the tensorflow .record. After I typed the command:

> python object_detection/dataset_tools/create_kitti_tf_record.py 
>   --lable_map_path=object_detection/data/kitti_label_map.pbtxt  --data_dir=/Users/zhenglyu/Graduate/research/DataSet/kitti/data_object_image_2/testing/image_2
>   --output_path=/Users/zhenglyu/Graduate/research/DataSet/kitti2tf/train.record
>   validation_set_size=1000

I got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "object_detection/dataset_tools/create_kitti_tf_record.py", line 310,
>   in 
>       tf.app.run()   File "/Users/zhenglyu/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py",
>   line 126, in run
>       _sys.exit(main(argv))   File "object_detection/dataset_tools/create_kitti_tf_record.py", line 307,
>   in main
>       validation_set_size=FLAGS.validation_set_size)   File "object_detection/dataset_tools/create_kitti_tf_record.py", line 94,
>   in convert_kitti_to_tfrecords
>       label_map_dict = label_map_util.get_label_map_dict(label_map_path)   File
>   "/Users/zhenglyu/Graduate/research/TensorFlow/model/research/object_detection/utils/label_map_util.py",
>   line 152, in get_label_map_dict
>       label_map = load_labelmap(label_map_path)   File "/Users/zhenglyu/Graduate/research/TensorFlow/model/research/object_detection/utils/label_map_util.py",
>   line 132, in load_labelmap
>       label_map_string = fid.read()   File "/Users/zhenglyu/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py",
>   line 120, in read
>       self._preread_check()   File "/Users/zhenglyu/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py",
>   line 80, in _preread_check
>       compat.as_bytes(self.**name), 1024 * 512, status)   File "/Users/zhenglyu/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py",
>   line 519, in __exit**
>       c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status)) **tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError:
>   data/kitti_label_map.pbtxt; No such file or directory**

The file exists for sure. And I don't know why as I set the label_map_path to another one (object_detection/data/kitti_label_map.pbtxt), the path still remains the default setting (data/kitti_label_map.pbtxt).

I know there's a lot of related problem but none of the solutions that I found works for me. I used Virtualenv to install the tensorflow and using python 3.6. Could these be the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Try to use absolute path

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Already tried absolute path but still having the issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a definitive solution to this but here is what resolved it.

First, I copied the kitti_label_map.pbtxt into the *data_dir*. Then I also copied create_kitti_tf_record.py into the data_dir. And now I copied(this is what made it run in the end) the name and absolute path of the kitti_label_map.pbtxt and pasted it as *label_map_path*

I have no idea why but it worked.